# Solution Explorer sometimes won't collapse folder, toggles triangle icon only

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, solution-explorer

I've been experiencing this odd problem intermittently in Visual Studio 2012 running on Windows 7. Sometimes, when I go to collapse a solution folder in Solution Explorer, the tree beneath the folder doesn't collapse at all. It only seems to toggle to a different expanded state, but the small triangle next to the folder name correctly toggles to the closed orientation. Here's what I mean:

**Exhibit A - Expanded Solution Folder**

Note the triangle next to Transitional is in the open orientation.

[image: Expanded Solution Folder]

Then, I click on the triangle next to Transitional to collapse the folder, but instead of what you'd expect, I get this result:

**Exhibit B - "Collapsed" Solution Folder**

Again, note that the triangle indicates that the folder is collapsed, though that it obviously not the case.

[image: "Collapsed" Solution Folder]

So far, the only action that temporarily fixes the problem is to close and reopen the solution, and I have yet to determine what causes the problem to recur. I wonder if any of you have experienced this, and if so, did you find a more permanent solution?

Comment: Not sure if it'll help in any way, but removing the solution's *.suo file can sometimes fix weird behaviors

Comment: It is a WPF TreeView control, part of the overhaul in VS2010 to "eat your own dogfood".  A principle that's strongly pursued at Microsoft.  WPF has, erm, ... issues.  This one is however not a common one.  Arbitrarily assume there's a try/catch that probably shouldn't catch.  But you weren't the first one, and VS crashing to the desktop sucks, so they added it anyway.  Look for memory problems, add-ins always go first.

Comment: Have you tried removing/disabling addins and extensions?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Do have any suggestion of what extension could cause this. Trial and error approach is going to take too much time to identify which extension cause this problem. Because there is no steps to reproduce this issue. It happens intermittently.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have never experienced this problem so I would be unsure which extension would be the culprit, or even if this is the problem.

Comment: We've just upgraded to VS2013 at my shop and so far I haven't experienced this issue with it. So that has become my "solution" to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am facing the same problem, try uninstall all plugins and reinstall. In my case this was caused by slow cheetah. Also, try repair visual studio

Comment: thank you, slow cheetah was my problem too. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this macro:

```
Sub UIHierarchy_CollapseTree()
Dim Hierarchy As UIHierarchy

'Change Hierarchy to the following line to collapse the active window
'Hierarchy = DTE.ActiveWindow.Object
Hierarchy = DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer).Object

CollapseHierarchyItems(Hierarchy.UIHierarchyItems)
End Sub
Sub CollapseHierarchyItems(ByVal HierarchyItems As UIHierarchyItems)
Dim SubHierarchyItem As UIHierarchyItem
For Each SubHierarchyItem In HierarchyItems
    CollapseHierarchyItems(SubHierarchyItem.UIHierarchyItems)
    SubHierarchyItem.UIHierarchyItems.Expanded = False
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: resharper has this built in btw